# Receiving "double free or corruption" only when deleting first node of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

The purpose of this program is to add a node at the end of a linked list that can be deleted through an ID.

I'm able to delete every node without issue except for the first node. Trying to do anything after deleting the first node causes unexpected behavior such as the linked list being cleared completely if I add more nodes, an infinite loop when trying to display the data inside the linked list and, or getting the error "double free or corruption".

Deleting Node

```
struct node* delete_node(struct node *list)

{

    struct node* p = list;
    struct node* prev, *temp;
    int id;

    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->id == id)
        {
            temp = p;
            p = p->next;
            prev->next = p;

            free(temp);
            printf("\nNode Deleted");
            return list;
        }
        prev = p;
        p = p->next;
    }

    printf("\nID not found");
    return list;
}
```

Adding Node

```
struct node *add_node(struct node *list)

{

    struct node *p;
    int id;

    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);

    for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        if(p->id == id)
        {
            printf("\nUser with this ID already exists.");
            return list;
        }
    }

    struct node *new_req;
    struct node *q = list;

    char username[UNAME_LEN], password[UNAME_LEN];

    printf("\nEnter username: ");
    read_line(username, UNAME_LEN);
    printf("\nEnter password: ");
    read_line(password, UNAME_LEN);

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError allocating memory!");
        return list;
    }

    strcpy(new_node->username, username);
    strcpy(new_node->password, password);
    new_node->id = id;

    if(list == NULL)
    {
        new_node->next = NULL;
        list = new_node;
        return list;

    }


    while(q->next != NULL)
        q = q->next;

    new_node->next = q->next;
    q->next = new_node;

    return list;

}
```

If I exit the program after deleting the first node I'll get "double free or corruption", if I add a new node after deleting the first node and attempt to display the data it'll cause an infinite loop. If I delete the first node, and add 2 additional nodes the linked list will be clear and I can exit out without error.

Comment: What your function is supposed to return after deleting the first node?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, It should return the updated linked list, if it's the only node in the linked list it should be NULL, if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: It should, but does it?

Comment: In the function `delete_node()`, the pointer `prev` is uninitialised.  If `p` is not NULL and `p->id == id` then the first thing done to `prev` is the assignment `prev->next = p`.    Even accessing `prev->next` (a necessary step before doing the assignment) gives undefined behaviour.  That will explain why deleting the first node fails - once behaviour is undefined, all bets are off in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deletion code doesn't work properly when you delete the first node in the list. A way to fix it might be:

```
    if(p->id == id)
    {
        if(p == list)
            list = list->next;
        else
            prev->next = p->next;

        free(p);
        printf("\nNode Deleted");
        return list;
    }
```

And the `temp` variable isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I tried using this and it's still the same issue, I can delete  every node except for the first one

Comment: @IAteYourCat: how do you call `delete_node`?

Comment: delete_node(new_list), in my main I have struct request *new_list = NULL;

Comment: @IAteYourCat: It shall be `new_list = delete_node(new_list)`.

Comment: This is not a correct way to delete a node in a doubly linked list. You need to update two pointers.

Comment: @n.m.: The OP has a singly linked list.

Comment: @ybungalobill indeed, my mistake

Comment: Many thanks, that fixed it. @n.m Thank you, I'll keep that in mind next time I post something here.